# iPHONE I get a white screen when I try to play a video I loaded and stored in Documents directory

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I did see some answers for this question, but they did not work.

I am loading a video from a web server, saving it in the documents directory and then trying to play it.  My first version saved it in the home directory and it worked fine.  When I change the code to save it in the documents directory, the video no longer played,

I tried using the following code to get the home directory, as posted when this same question was asked.

```
NSString *userDocumentsPath = nil;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] > 0) 
{
    userDocumentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

The code to save the video

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Save vedio
NSFileManager *mFile= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *userDocumentsPath = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] > 0) 
{
    userDocumentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSString *filename=[userDocumentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ted.mp4"];

b=[mFile createFileAtPath:filename contents: receivedData attributes:nil];

if ( [mFile fileExistsAtPath:filename]==true )
    i++;
```

the code to play the video

```
NSString *userDocumentsPath = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                       NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] > 0) 
{
    userDocumentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSString *filename=[userDocumentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ted.mp4"];
// play it
NSURL *fileUrl=[ NSURL fileURLWithPath:filename];//
mp=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: fileUrl];
```

Comment: make sure that the target file is already in document directory

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, it works in IOS 4.3 and lower, but not in IOS 5 simulator/device. I have googled for hours and tried different solutions, but not found anything that works yet.

Comment: same problem . Any one found solution?